# Flutter horizontal swipe gesture in webview

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a Flutter App right now, that has a login, which routes to a new screen, which contains a scaffold, which holds a webView as a body. For the navigation I use

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
  context,
  webshopRoute,
  arguments: WebshopArguments(initialUrl: shopUrl),
);
```

When I browse in the webView I want to go back - within the webView - with a swipe gesture from right to left(for phones that don't have a back button like my Pixel 4). But what the swipe does right now is that it jumps back to the Login Screen.

The only posts I found here where how to disable it, which I don't want.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the trick was to wrap the scaffold with WillPopScope and call goBack() on the controller inside onWillPop.

```
late WebViewController _webViewController;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        _webViewController.goBack();
        return false;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: WebView(javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                 onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                 _webViewController = webViewController;
                 },
.....
```